# Actualizar texto cada cierto tiempo mientras la ventana esté ativa

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Me gustaría hacer algo similar a este script:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set('hello')

l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
l.pack()

for i in range(6):
    sleep(1) # Need this to slow the changes down
    var.set('goodbye' if i%2 else 'hello')
    root.update_idletasks()
```

Pero que el texto quede fijo y no se cierre la ventana. Necesito que pueda cambiar el texto y se refleje mientras la ventana este activa. Esto ha sido lo mas parecido que he conseguido.

Comment: Hola Eus, he creado una respuesta que espero te resulte de ayuda a pesar de la tardanza. Para otra vez recuerda añadir siempre la etiqueta principal del lenguaje ([tag:python]), esto, para empezar, hará tu pregunta más visible ( y por tanto es posible que se te responda antes), dado que mucha más gente sigue esta etiqueta que la de [tag:tkinter]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El cambio de texto lo realizas en un ciclo `for` que itera seis veces, al terminar el label no cambiará más. Necesitas que el ciclo sea infinito si quieres que esto suceda mientras la app esté ene ejecución, no obstante, unos  apuntes primero:

- No uses *wildcard* (`from tkinter import *`) para importar en Python a no ser que esté plenamente justificado, dificulta la legibilidad del código y facilita el solapamiento de nombres no deseados. Es una mala práctica, muy extendida en tkinter por culpa de algunos viejos tutoriales.
- Si ese es todo tu código, te falta llamar al ciclo principal de la aplicación (`root.mainloop`). En caso contrario la app no iniciará jamás, a no ser que la ejecutes en el IDLE, el cual está programado en tkinter y su propio mainloop es usado para tu aplicación.
- Como norma general, no se debe usar llamadas bloqueantes dentro del hilo principal de una aplicación gráfica. Esto causa que se bloquee el mainloop, el cual no puede responder a eventos ni redibujar la interfaz mientras tanto, provocando el congelamiento de la interfaz. `time.sleep` es la función bloqueante por excelencia...

  En tu caso lo palías mediante `update_idletasks` entre iteraciones, pero si aumentas el tiempo de `sleep` la aplicación quedará congelada durante demasiado tiempo y algunos SO (como Windows) empiezan a quejarse, además, durante ese tiempo no puedes interactuar con la app.

En realidad quieres ejecutar una tarea, no bloqueante en si (cambiar el texto de un label) cada cierto tiempo. Para esto tkinter (al igual que la mayoría de frameworks) tiene algo ya pensado, el método `after`.

`after` permite programar la ejecución de una *callback* pasado un tiempo determinado que especificamos.

Su firma es:

```
after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args)
```

el primer argumento es el tiempo de espera en milisegundos, el segundo una referencia al *callable* a ejecutar. Además permite añadir un numero indeterminado de argumentos que serán pasados al *callable* como argumentos.

La llamada solo se programa una vez, si queremos que se repita indefinidamente debemos programarla de nuevo, lo cual podemos hacer desde la propia función a ejecutar.

```
import tkinter as tk


def update_label():
    var.set("hello" if var.get() == "goodbye" else "goodbye")
    l.after(1000, update_label)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")
var = tk.StringVar()
var.set('Hello')

l = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var, fg="#660066", font=(None, 30))
l.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
update_label()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### EXTRA

Dejo otro ejemplo del uso de `after` que tenía por ahí, un semáforo:

```
import itertools
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg="#66FFFF")
canvas.grid()

canvas.create_rectangle(190, 20, 310, 420,  outline="#000000", fill="#193300", width=3)
canvas.create_rectangle(235, 420, 265, 500, outline="#000000", fill="#000000", width=3)
canvas.create_oval(200, 50, 300, 150, outline="#000000", fill="#330000", width=3)
canvas.create_oval(200, 170, 300, 270, outline="#000000", fill="#663300", width=3)
canvas.create_oval(200, 290, 300, 390, outline="#000000", fill="#003319", width=3)
canvas.create_oval(200, 50, 300, 150, tag=("light", "red"), outline="#000000", fill="#FF0000", width=3)
canvas.create_oval(200, 170, 300, 270, tag=("light", "orange"), outline="#000000", fill="#FFC522", width=3)
canvas.create_oval(200, 290, 300, 390, tag=("light", "green"), outline="#000000", fill="#1f1", width=3)
root.wm_title("Circles and Arcs")


def run(timer):
    t = next(timer)
    canvas.tag_lower("light")
    canvas.tag_raise(t[0])
    canvas.after(t[1], run, timer)

t = [("green", 6000),
     ("", 200),
     ("orange", 2000),
     ("", 500),
     ("orange", 2000),
     ("", 500),
     ("orange", 2000),
     ("", 200),
     ("red", 6000),
     ("", 200)
     ]

timer = itertools.cycle(t)
run(timer)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ### **IMPORTANTE**
>
> `after` permite llamar a la función pasado un tiempo dado, sin bloquear la app mientras se espera, pero **no ejecuta la propia función de forma asíncrona**. es decir, si la función tarda mucho en ejecutarse la app se bloquea igualmente. En este caso se debe recurrir a un hilo o proceso secundario para ejecutar la tarea bloqueante.